# Duplicate questions but each has some useful answers

Tags: discussion

Looking at [Move all files from one folder to another, based on a list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377417/move-all-files-from-one-folder-to-another-based-on-a-list) and [move file by list in file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115734/move-file-by-list-in-file)

The more recent one has been validly suggested as a duplicate of the older, and is likely to get marked as such. However, each of the questions has some useful different answers.

If the new question gets closed in favour of the old one people are likely to jump to that older one. And, of course, vice versa. I should point out I have provided an answer on the newer question - not having known at the time there was a duplicate.

Can and/or should these questions be merged? Or do I wait until the new one is closed and then repost my own answer against the old but open question?

What's etiquette in this kind of situation (and perhaps more importantly, what's the most useful/appropriate way of offering an answer that will get seen)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would just post a comment on the older question linking directly to your answer and stating, *"You can also [do this with `rsync`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377424/135943), which has an option expressly for this purpose."*  (Note the link style, [avoiding "here" links](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/).)

---

The new one is closed now, so if you *want* to move your answer, you can.

---

I don't know enough about the mechanics of merging to judge that.  They do seem to be asking the same question, except that in one of them there is extra whitespace in the filename list.  That may make a difference to some answers.  (Would `rsync --files-from` work with extra leading whitespace in the list?)

Nice answer, by the way.  `rsync` is a crazy power tool.

Comment: inappropriate +1 just for the "here" link ... link...

Comment: How would I move my answer (while keeping its votes)? Via a moderator, I guess? Problem is that it doesn't answer the specific case of the other question (and on that point they're not perfect duplicates). It's a trivial fix to strip the leading whitespace before passing to `--files-from` but it then includes unnecessary code for the question it was intended to answer.

Comment: @roaima, right.  So I think a link (via comment) is more applicable.